# Angular 2 shared service to pass data to component-to-component

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to pass the string value of `this.title` from my LandingPage.component to my ResultPage.component.

I retrieve the `list.show` value, and send it to my `TitleService` in like so in my:

*landingpage.component.html*

```
<ol>
  <li (click)="selectShow(list.show)" [routerLink]="['/details', list.id]" *ngFor="let list of shows">{{list.show}}
  </li>
</ol>
```

*landingpage.component.ts*

```
import { TitleService } from '../../services/title.service';

constructor(private TitleService: TitleService) {}

selectShow(show) {
  this.TitleService.fetchTitle(show)
}
```

The above sends the `list.show` value to my:

*title.service.ts*

```
// this gives us the name of the clicked show, which we send to TitleResolver
@Injectable()
export class TitleService {
  fetchTitle(title) {
    console.log("title is " + title); // this outputs correctly
    return title;
  }
}
```

And here is how I manage the routing in my:

*app-routing.module.ts*

```
import { TitleService } from './services/title.service';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LandingPage },
  {
    path: 'details/:id', component: ResultPage
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [TitleService]
})
```

**My question**

Once I receive the `title.show` value in my service component, I'm unsure how to then send it to my receiving component (*resultpage.component*)

How can I send my `title` value from my service to my ResultPage.component?

Comment: Rather than using a service, have you thought about using redux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the title a public property of the service like this:

```
// this gives us the name of the clicked show, which we send to TitleResolver
@Injectable()
export class TitleService {
  selectedTitle: string;

  fetchTitle(title) {
    console.log("title is " + title); // this outputs correctly
    this.selectedTitle = title;
    return title;   // No need to return it.
  }
}
```

Then any other component can inject this service and access `this.titleService.selectedTitle`

Answer (score 2):

In `title.service.ts` you can declare a variable called `title` and have setter and getter:

```
title: string ="";

// replace fetchTitle with setTitle 
// remember to change it in the component too
setTitle(title) {
    this.title = title;
  }

getTitle() {
    return this.title;
  }
```

Then, when `ResultPage.component` is initialized, call `getTitle()` from `TitleService` and set the result to a variable declared in the component.

Here's an [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/juF6ICGAqPbXkEHkBuFW?p=preview) of sharing data via shared services.

Comment: Thank you! This is also a great method, I tried it out and it works great. I'm not really sure which is best practice between your answer and DeborahK's. But both of them work well.

Answer (score 0):

Separation of concerns...  Your landing page is used to select the list item and navigate to the result page.  Let it do just that and only that.  Let the ResultPage.component do the rest.   Note:  Other answers recommend storing the value of the last title in the TitleService.  It's not a good idea to store state in a service.  Then TitleService cannot be used as a generic way to get any title separate from your current navigation, without side effects.

Remove (click) event.  Add 'show' as a QueryParam.

landingpage.component.html

```
<li [routerLink]="['/details', list.id]" 
    [queryParams]="{show: list.show}" 
     *ngFor="let list of shows">
     {{list.show}}
</li>
```

Subscribe to router params and queryparams to get the id and show.

resultpage.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { TitleService } from '../../services/title.service';

@Component({
  ...
})
export class ResultPageComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

 itemId: string;
 show: string;
 subParams: any;       // infinite Observable to be unsubscribed
 subQueryParams: any;  // infinite Observable to be unsubscribed

 constructor(
          ... 
          private TitleService: TitleService,
          protected route: ActivatedRoute,
          protected router: Router,
          ...
 ) {}

 ngOnInit() {
   this.subParams = this.route.params.subscribe(this.onParams);
   this.subQueryParams = this.route.queryParams(this.onQueryParams);
 }

 ngOnDestroy() {
   // Delete active subscribes on destroy
   this.subParams.unsubscribe();  
   this.subQueryParams.unsubscribe();  
 }

 onParams = (params: any) => {
   this.itemId = params['id'];
 }

 onQueryParams = (data: any) => {
  this.show = data.show;
  if(this.show) {
    this.TitleService.fetchTitle(this.show)
  }
 }
```