# How to create global variables between two components with data update in angular 2/4?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-services

How to create the global variables in angular2/4 with data update of each time with a button click.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow, Please add some description of your problem. Also read the guidelines before posting. Have fun.
Also,You can use inputs and output or services for communications between your components

Comment: Use a data sharing service. I will google it for you :/  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35273106/angular2-share-data-between-components-using-services

Comment: You can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44915111/5556177). Also the [doc](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/angular/10836/sharing-data-among-components#t=201708011230246435098) has multiple examples.

Comment: Thanks, Steve and Faisal. Can you guys help me to reload the current view in the service method calling

Comment: use a service to share the data between components. Services are singleton so, you can import same service object to different components to access common data.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Create TS, you can put in any folder. For example /config.ts

```
export const ConfigService = Object.freeze({
    apiAuthURL: 'http://api.domain.com'
});
```

To use it, add import on the top:

```
import { ConfigService } from "./config";

export class DataService {
   constructor(){
       let authURL = ConfigService.apiAuthURL;
    }
}
```