# How to access parent component properties from a child route component in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, routes, parent-child

I'm new to Angular and I'm stuck there.
I know how to share data between parent and child components simply by injecting [parentData]="var" into the child selector <>.

But when using routing; I only have a router-outlet and can't bind [parentData] to it as it throws an error.

What is the best and easiest way to access parent properties from a child's route?

The project is on [stackblitz here](http://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s66atk).

I need to display products (from the parent component) inside the child component.

version:(Angular 5)

Comment: You can not pass variables from a component in other component that you have in  a router-outlet. You must use a service to share data. A service is the same along the "app live"
in https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service you have as comunicate parent and children, but if the only you want to do is more simple https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44914707/angular-2-shared-service-to-pass-data-to-component-to-component

Comment: A resolver is a service, and it is done specifically for that purpose: https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-guard

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes this is pretty simple, when you want to pass to component that are in `router-outlet` you need to use `services`, actually that component do not exist in the template before you go to the right path, so usual bindings don't work here.

So the best way to work this around is to create some simple service

## In the service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class DataTransferService {

  private products= new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);
  cast= this.products.asObservable();

  sendAnything(data) {
    this.products.next(data);
  }

}
```

then inject your service into both constructors of your parent and child component

## In parent component

```
 constructor(private dataTransfer: DataTransferService){}
```

then create a method

```
 shareData(data){
    this.dataTransfer.sendAnything(data) // to send something
}
```

and call it from the parent.component.html with

```
(click)="shareData(data)" // data is the parent data that you want to share
```

## In child component

inside the ngOnInit method add:

```
 ngOnInit() {
   this.dataTransfer.products.subscribe(res=> this.var = res) // var is the property that you want to assign the data to it.
 }
```

to get the data and work with it.
more info and examples You can find in [doc](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur answer, i'll try it now. but I havent used Subjects before ,   what do yourVariable, sourceProductName, sourceYourVariable  stand for?

Comment: Sorry i made some typo there. Subject is a kind type of observable that we can control and call .next() method to send new value to a stream, yourVariable is an actual Observable that you can subscribe and listen to any stuff that was sent from another place in the application

Comment: I have edited the answer to help others who staarting to learn angular like me.. I spent time to search and figure out how to make use of the anser, hence the downvote for me is not fair. thank you

Comment: You need to check it as a right answer if it was the right one. No problem, hope it help some1

Comment: Are you gonna remove the downvote if you put it please?

Comment: this did not work for me, the docs is using `Subject` and not `BehaviorSubject`, using `Subject` worked https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Answer (score 5):

On the one hand, you can not pass an input to the router-outlet tag since the component added by the router will be a sibling to the  tag and won't replace it.

On the other, When your Angular application becomes more and more complex, passing the same input from the parent components to the child ones will no longer be the right way to do things..

In your case, the best way to deal with the products variable is to declare it as a behavior subject in the products service:

```
   prodcuts:Subject<IProducts[]> = new BehaviorSubject<IProducts[]>([]);
```

and in the parent component, you send the received data:

```
ngOnInit() { 
    this._productsService.getProducts()
        .subscribe(
          data => {this.products = data;
          this._productsService.prodcuts.next(data);
          },
          error => this.errMsg = error
        );    
}
```

Finally, in the child client you have to subscribe to the behavior subject declared in the service:

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
public products = [];

constructor(private _productsService: ProductsService ) { 
}

ngOnInit() {
    this._productsService.prodcuts
    .subscribe(
      data => {
       {this.products = data;
      }
    );    
  } 
}
```

Comment: This seems an efficient solution, i'll try it shortly. thank you

Comment: And thank you for applying my previous code with the productService, i did update it later for simplicity, but your code will be much helpful in my case. will work on it in few hours, thank you very much

Comment: Can you please explain: in the child component, what is the difference between subscribing to products and subscribing to getProducts() like what we do inside the parent component? I'm not clear on that.